# c# include a variable in a string of data for JSON

Tags: c#, json, string, variables

I'm trying to pass c# variables into the following string and I've got really lost around how to do it.

This is the string without the use of variables:

```cs
string data = @"{ ""fields"": { 
    ""project"":
    {
        ""key"": ""TEST""
    },
    ""summary"": ""Test Ticket"",
    ""description"": ""test"",
    ""issuetype"": {""name"": ""test""},
    ""assignee"": { ""name"": ""test""}
}}";
```

Then when I try to include a variable (test.Text is a asp textbox) I do it this way:

```cs
string data = @"{ ""fields"": { 
    ""project"":
    {
        ""key"": ""TEST""
    },
    ""summary"": ""Test Ticket"",
    ""description"": """ + test.Text + """,
    ""issuetype"": {""name"": ""test""},
    ""assignee"": { ""name"": ""test"" }
}}";
```

But that isn't working. Is there a different way to include variable data in there?

When I try and build it then it says

> } expected.

So I went through and tried to wrap each one in `}` like this, but it didn't help :(

```cs
string data = @"{ ""fields"": { 
    ""project"":
    {
        ""key"": ""TEST""
    },
    ""summary"": ""Test Ticket"",
    ""description"": {""" + test.Text + """},
    ""issuetype"": {""name"": ""test""},
    ""assignee"": { ""name"": ""test"" }
}}";
```

Thanks!

Comment: What specifically "isn't working" about it?

Comment: Don't build JSON like that. All kinds of fun (cough, cough) is going to happen once `test.Text` has quotes etc in it.

Comment: instead of manipulating strings in order to build valid JSON you should definitly use a serializer and let it write proper JSON, e.g. `JsonConvert`.

Comment: The code doesn't compile because the second literal string isn't verbatim, it would have to be `+ test.Text + @"""},`, but as have been said, the proper way to build json is not to do it with string concatenation, use a proper Json library for this.

Comment: You might want to change the title of this question to say something like, "how to create a JSON object in C#". In my personal opinion, it better represents what you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to make a JSON object. You are better off creating a class that is a blueprint for the JSON object. Then use NewtonSoft to convert to a JSON string.

```
namespace example
{
    public class Ticket
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Ticket tic = new Ticket()
            {
                Id = 123,
                Description = "hello motto"
            };

            Console.WriteLine(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tic));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

yields the results

```
{"Id":123,"Description":"hello motto"}
```

Also note that you can put classes in classe and it will nest it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use string interpolation in order to achieve that, but much better (and less error prone) would be using some JSON related classes like `JObject` from Newtonsoft or the JSON.NET package.

For example, this is how you would add a variable to a JObject:

```cs
JObject data = new JObject()
{ 
    {"description", test.Text}
};
```

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

I concur with the other commenters, that this is a clunky and *very* unmaintainable way to build up a JSON string. This is an excellent library to use instead: [Newtonsoft JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

If you *must* do it this way for some reason, I suggest using the much improved [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) which was made available starting in C#6.

Here is how that would look:

```cs
string data = $@"{{ ""fields"": {{ 
    ""project"":
    {{
        ""key"": ""TEST""
    }},
    ""summary"": ""Test Ticket"",
    ""description"": ""{test.Text}"",
    ""issuetype"": {{""name"": ""test""}},
    ""assignee"": {{ ""name"": ""test""}}
}}";
```

**Note:** This is technically an "interpolated verbatim string" (notice the $@) so now the brackets need to be escaped.